# c++ - Can't solve SIGABRT

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb, sigabrt

Im trying to run a simple code, it compiles but when i try to run it i get (core dumped) erro. So used gdb to see what the error was.

code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


void gerar()
{
    printf("works\n");
}

int main()
{
    std::thread oi(gerar);
    printf("oi");

    return 0;
}
```

dgb msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in <module>
    from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff6fd6700 (LWP 4879)]
terminate called without an active exception

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7313cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

g++ line:

```
g++ -c teste.cpp -pthread -std=c++11  
g++ teste.o -o teste -pthread -std=c++11
```

Comment: You need a oi.join() in main. Main is terminating with an active thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

destructor of thread:

> If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called.

And it is your case.

Call `oi.join();` in `main`.